# Objects coordinates do not match group coordinates

Tags: javascript, graphics, fabricjs

I do have a group with multiple objects. If the group is not rotated. Everything looks fine and controls are as expected.

However, when I take exactly the same group and set the rotation angle programmatically before rendering, my controls coordinates equal the bounding rect, but not the group coordinates anymore.

I have created a simplied version of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/schacki/avd6sjps/2/

```
fabric.Object.prototype.originX = "center";
fabric.Object.prototype.originY = "center";

// init canvas
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var angle = 20;

// Group 1: no rotation
var left1 = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'red',
  left:75,
  top: 75,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center"
});
var middle1 = new fabric.Rect({
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'green',
  width: 300,
  height: 100,
  left: 200,
  top: 100,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center"
});
var right1 = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  left:325,
  top: 125,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center"
});
var group1 = new fabric.Group([middle1, left1, right1],{angle: 45});

// Group 1: no rotation
var left2 = new fabric.Rect({
  angle: 45,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'red',
  left:75+54,
  top: 275-80,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center"
});
var middle2 = new fabric.Rect({
    angle: 45,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'green',
  width: 300,
  height: 100,
  left: 200,
  top: 300,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center"
});
var right2 = new fabric.Rect({
  angle: 45,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  left:325-54,
  top: 325+80,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center"
});
var group2 = new fabric.Group([middle2, left2, right2]);

canvas.add(group1);
canvas.add(group2);
canvas.setActiveObject(group1);

canvas.setActiveObject(group2);
```

Basically I would like to have the controls in group 2 to look like the controls of group 1. Thanks

Comment: that is an exact duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897935/controls-coordinates-do-not-match-group-coordinates

Comment: There is no reply for that, that's why created new.

Comment: Same question same code. They will stay unswared both or answered both. What is the point? Just different user?

Comment: staying unanswered, i need help on this topic that's why created new one.    Still i didn't get any answer for the question.